# Sending a render request to a personal server

Tags: rendering, export

I own a game website where users can customise their avatars (to display the avatars in 3d I use treejs) but recently I found out that I needed also rendered profile pictures for the users.

My idea is that when a user edit their avatar, it sends a render request (via php?) to my old laptop (that I want to use as a "rendering server" where it runs blender on linux) and after it rendered it on blender it uploads it back to the webserver database.

How can I achieve this?

I am not an expert so I asked my friends for ideas and they said I could use some python or ssh or maybe I could use telnet.

Sorry if the question is vague, but I have no idea of how to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

### Run a render with a Bash command

You can use a bash command to run a render, something like :

```
blender -b my_file.blend -o output_picture_name -f 1
```

For more informations about arguments you can look at the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/command_line/render.html) or type :

```
man blender
```

### Run a Bash command with a script

In python, it would look like :

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run(["blender", "-b", "my_file.blend", "-o", "picture", "-f", "1"])
if(result.returncode == 0):
    print("Everything went good")
else:
    print("Something went wrong")
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks very helpful! Can this be executed by the users on the website using a proper php command? (like the one on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735250/running-a-python-script-from-php )